# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given -- errors comes up when creating stack class by numPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stack

I want to create a stack class using a numPy array  but this error comes up

> TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
import numpy as np

class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Stack =np.Stack([])

    def push(self,data):
            return self.Stack.append(data)
            print("stack overfolow")

    def pop(self):
        if len(self.Stack)==0:
            print("stack underflow")
        else:
            return self.Stack.pop()
    def __len(self):
        return len(self.Stack)

    def top(self):
        if len(self.Stack)==0:
            print("stack under flow")
        else:
            return self.Stack[len(self.Stack)-1]

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.Stack) == 0

    def is_full(self):
        return len(self.Stack) == self.limit


    def size(self):
        return len(self.Stack)
```

Comment: On what line ? Don't name your class the same as the attribut

Comment: `np.Stack` doesn't exists, so ?

Comment: Get this working with lists before trying it with numpy.

Comment: Report the full error, not just a freehand approximation.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the code that calls/constructs your object - i.e., full code we can cut and paste and run ourselves - and the full stack trace, as someone else asked.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `self.Stack =np.Stack([])` with `self.stack = np.stack([0,0])`

Reason, numpy has a method stack that stacks 2 arrays on top of each other and it requires something to be stacked. Also by using lower case instead of upper case you follow [pep8 recomendation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Even tough that would work, I believe what you want is to replace `np.stack` with `np.array`, reason being you don't need to stack anything right now, and only need the return value of stack that is itself an np.array